# How do you update pagination links if they are not refreshing on a Solr search request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, will-paginate

I have been using `solr` search and now I am adding pagination via the `will_paginate` gem. Loading the initial page works with the pagination links on the bottom of the webpage rendering correctly and working fine, but when I do a search via Solr the **pagination links do not get updated**.  It always loads the 155 pagination links for the non-search compared to at most the 2 pagination link for a search. They retain the old links from the initial page load.

books.rb:

```
  def self.search(query,page)
    search = Sunspot.search(Book) do
      keywords query
      paginate :page => page, :per_page => 10
    end
    search.results
  end
```

books_controller.rb:

```
  def index
    if params[:query] && !params[:query].blank?
      @books = Book.search(params[:query],:page => params[:page])
    else
      @books = Book.order_by(:title).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    end
  end
```

index.html.erb:

```
  <%= form_tag books_path, :method => :get, :remote => true, :id => "book_search" do  %>
    <div><%= label_tag :query, "Search" %> <%= text_field_tag "query", "" %></div>
    <div><%= submit_tag "Find", :class => "" %></div>
  <% end %>
  <div><%= will_paginate @books %></div>
```

I have both the `will_paginate` and `sunspot` gems installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can shorten the line

```
if params[:query] && !params[:query].blank?
```

into just

```
if params[:query].present?
```

as it will accomplish the same thing.

Are you sure you are hitting the correct code branch and not running the `Book.order_by` line? and are you sure you are testing it with different values of the `page` parameter?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm not running the `Book.order_by` line because it would load a huge list compared to `Book.search` which will only load a few items. It always shows the same 155 pagination link compared to a search which would at most be 2 pagination links. Thanks for the tip on using `present?`

Comment: so, the problem is not that the pagination links dont work, but rather that you are getting more results back than you expected to??  In that case you'd probably have to past your `User` model search settings so we can see what is getting indexed as well as a sample query.  Even then, without your dataset it could be hard to know why you are getting more than expected.

Comment: Its that I'm getting more results, its the pagination links not refreshing correctly after the search. I'll add the presentation code. Thanks